# SSRS RDL timeout settings

Tags: reporting-services

We have couple of long running reports in SSRS.  It is rendering fine in ReportViewer.   When we try to export to PDF, it times out after some time.  We increased  httprequesttimeout in ReportServer Web.config and it works fine in Offshore.  Our onshore environment is a shared one and the client is not inclined to change setting in shared environment.  We have tried changing invidual reports time out properties(Do not time out and also Manually given the time out to some big number).  Unfortunately it seems to be overridden by reportserver web.config entry httprequesttimeout which is 2 minutes by default.

Is there a way to override individual report's timeout settings instead of changing Reportserver web.config

Regards
K.P.Kannan

Comment: Do not time out doesn't work at all? Sounds like a bug or something wacky. What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Can you set up the report to use a snapshot or tune the underlying query?  In my experience with rendering to PDF, this problem turns out to be a poorly constructed query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about execution time-out value. I've found something on Microsoft, hope it helps.

> **How report execution time-out values are evaluated**
>
> The report server evaluates running jobs at 60 second intervals. At
> each 60 second interval, the report server compares actual process
> time against the report execution time-out value. If the processing
> time for a report exceeds the report execution time-out value, report
> processing will stop.
>
> Note that if you specify a time-out value that is smaller than 60
> seconds, the report may execute in full if processing starts and
> completes during the quiet part of the cycle when the report server is
> not evaluating running jobs. For example, if you set a time-out value
> of 10 seconds for a report that takes 20 seconds to run, the report
> will process in full if report execution starts early in the 60 second
> cycle.

Here is the link for details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/setting-time-out-values-for-report-and-shared-dataset-processing-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017